# Animation duration ignored for sublayerTransform

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

The following results in the view being scaled up from 1/2 size over two seconds;

```
myView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(
    CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
    myView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
})
```

The following however, results in the view being scaled up immediately - ignoring the duration;

```
myView.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(
    CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
    myView.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
})
```

Why is `sublayerTransform` not animating over the duration?  `CALayer` notes that it is Animatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't animate `sublayerTransform` via `UIView.animate`.  Instead, use a `CABasicAnimation`.

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "sublayerTransform")
animation.fromValue = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(
    CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
animation.duration = 2
myView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "sublayerTransform")
myView.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
```